# how to delete a key in array and rebuild the array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'Investment' =>
    array(15) {
      'id' =>
     string(36) "53d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b" ...
```

I would like to remove the Investment key and do the new array should be

```
    array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(15) {
      'id' =>
     string(36) "53d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b" ...
```

how do I do it?

Comment: `$array[0]=$array[0]['Investment'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return the value of the 'Investment' key for each item.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['Investment'];
}, $oldArray);
```

If you do not want to copy the array, you can possibly try to use [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

**Edit: solution using array_walk()**

```
array_walk($oldArray, function(&$item) {
    $item = $item['Investment'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the array to `array_map` as such:

```
$array = [
    [ 'Investment' => [ 'id' => '13d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b' ] ],
    [ 'Investment' => [ 'id' => '23d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b' ] ],
    [ 'Investment' => [ 'id' => '33d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b' ] ],
    [ 'Investment' => [ 'id' => '43d64bec-031c-4732-b2e0-755799154b1b' ] ]
];

$mappedArray = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val['Investment'];
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

store investment array in temp variable and unset as similar as given below

```
$tempArr = // 0 index of your array
foreach($tempArr as $key=>$val){
     if(!empty($val['Investment'])){
       $temp = $val['Investment'];
    unset($val['Investment']);
    $val[] = $temp;
}

}
```